# Laser engraving software for Boxzy 3D printer

Tags: software, laser, 2d

I have a laser-engraving "head" for one of my 3D printers (a Boxzy, so it's designed for it, not just strapping a random laser onto something), and I'd like to try using it to, well, *engrave* something. So:

- Can anyone point me to some control software for this?

The Boxzy came with a license to Fusion360, but I found that nearly impossible to use (or maybe understand), and it wasn't clear how to apply it to engraving anyway (as opposed to milling or regular FDM printing).

I suppose I could just sketch out a thin 3D extrusion of the text or design, and print it in the usual way, setting the layer-height and/or scaling so it only "prints" one or 2 layers. I guess turning the laser on and off counts as turning the extruder motor on and off... But that's clearly a hack. Any "real" software for this sort of thing?

Any other hints are also welcome.

I'm thinking of writing my own software to generate G-code for this, though rasterizing fonts sounds painful in something like OpenScad... Must be a better way...

Answer (score 2):

Autodesk must have been reading your mind.

A brand new video just got posted today from Autodesk on how to do this in F360.
[image]

Comment: Thanks! Maybe they even have somebody reading this forum. :)  Will check it out (though will have to renew my license to use it....)

Comment: Or you could help mentor a First Robotics Team and get to use it for free (non-commercially)

Comment: Mind to elaborate on this a little as the link might die in the future, orphaning this answer?